# Label and scale on coord_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to visualize my dataframe with a simple bar plot using coord_polar.I am trying to reproduce this screenshot:

[image]

Here is my try:

```
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month, y=Percent)) + 
   geom_col(aes(fill= Month ), width = 0.87 )+
  coord_polar()+
  labs(title="some title ", 
       subtitle="% of total number of something",
       x="", 
       y="",
       caption="Reaserch")+
  theme_minimal(10) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        text=element_text(family="Courier"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=12, hjust=0.2, face='bold'),
        plot.subtitle=element_text(size=11, hjust=0.2),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, hjust=0.1, face='bold'),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

result
[image]

I would like to remove background grid and top left axis and show month and value for each record inside the pie (ex. Aug 68%) + where is the right place to define `color = "Yellow"`  ?

```
# reproducible sample data
df <- tibble::tribble(
       ~Month, ~Percent,
    "Jan",    68,
   "Feb",    68,
      "Mar",    68,
      "Apr",    68,
        "May",    68,
       "June",    65,
       "July",    52,
     "Aug",    60,
  "Sept",    68,
    "Oct",    68,
   "Nov",    68,
   "Dec",    68
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df$Month_label = paste0(df$Month, "\n", df$Percent, "%") %>% fct_inorder

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Month_label, y=Percent)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "#ffc97b", width = 0.87 )+
  geom_text(aes(label = Month_label, y = Percent - 10)) +
  coord_polar()+
  labs(title="some title ", 
       subtitle="% of total number of something",
       x="", 
       y="",
       caption="Research")+
  theme_minimal(10) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(family="Courier"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=12, hjust=0.2, face='bold'),
        plot.subtitle=element_text(size=11, hjust=0.2),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am just wondering If later I want to add total at the top of each pie slice where should add the new variable? ex: Aug 68% as it is but 1980 at the top of slice ( like month label on my try)

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you have in mind. If you want to show the axis text, remove `axis.text = element_blank()` and you could make the axis have the labels you want (probably as a factor so that it retains the order you want).